# How to find ellipsoid bounding the intersection of an ellipsoid and half-space?

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, ellipsoids

How does one prove that the bounding ellipsoid $E(A', a')$ of the intersection of an ellipsoid $E(A,a) = [ x | (x-a)^TA^{-1}(x-a) ]$ and half-space $H = [x |  c^Tx \le c^Ta ]$ is given by the following: (all in n-dimensional space over the reals)

[image]

Where $b = (1/\sqrt{c^TAc})Ac$

Where did $A'$ and $a'$ expressions come from? Thanks in advance!

References: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid_method 
https://www.zib.de/groetschel/pubnew/paper/groetschellovaszschrijver1988.pdf pg.70 is the above image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have the proof for you, but I do have some good reading material: Martin Henk, "Löwner-John Ellipsoids", [Documenta Mathematica](http://www.emis.ams.org/journals/DMJDMV/Welcome-eng.html), [Extra Volume: Optimization Stories (2012)](http://www.emis.ams.org/journals/DMJDMV/vol-ismp/vol-ismp.html), pp. 95-106. A PDF of this article [can be found here](http://www.emis.ams.org/journals/DMJDMV/vol-ismp/24_henk-martin.pdf). These are stable links.

A discussion of Khachiyan's ellipsoid algorithm begins on page 101; at the top of this page, you will see a figure depicting the construction of an enclosing ellipsoid. There you will also find several references that discuss the theoretical development of the algorithm; and certainly, in one of those references, you will find a derivation and/or proof of the above formulae.

Perhaps you will find the article a sufficiently interesting treatment of the general topic that you won't need to worry yourself with a specific proof :-)

Comment: As a general question, when going through this type of maths, how concerned should I be about being able to see a proof of everything? I started this habit in undergrad, but now I study CVX material on my own and I've mostly been stubborn about seeing where every formula comes from. Is this still a good approach? My goal is to one day study applied math in grad school, but in the meantime I'm enjoying applying CVX to various data analysis contract software gigs. Thanks for your response Mr. Grant, I'll go through those resources.

Comment: You're welcome, and thanks for the kind words about CVX. I am sure opinions differ widely, but I *personally* do not expect to be able to prove every result about convex optimization that I encounter. I rely on others to do that so that I can focus on my niche. What works for you will depend on the specific focus you choose to pursue in grad school. We need people focused on theoretical development, just as we need people focused on helping people actually solve problems. They feed each other...

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Hmm I still haven't found my 'niche' yet, but this is a valuable perspective. Back on topic, for anyone wondering, I found the relevant proofs in Appendix B (p. 1082) of: http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~cswamy/courses/co759/approx-material/ellipsoid-survey.pdf which was a reference in the answer's paper.

Comment: Good find! You should post that as as a separate answer.

Answer (score 2):

I found the relevant proofs in Appendix B (p. 1082) of:

http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~cswamy/courses/co759/approx-material/ellipsoid-survey.pdf

Which was a reference in the paper posted by Michael Grant. Interestingly, it proves the bounding ellipsoid update formulas for more general cases than my question asked. I.e. for different parameters of alpha the cuts are deep cuts or shallow cuts, etc (interesting because for a deep cut, the new bounding ellipsoid will be lower volume, so possibly faster algorithm convergence).